# How to fix the Future<bool> vs bool error in flutter dart when using the shared preferences library?

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart

I'm pretty new to flutter, and I have little experience with asynchronous coding, so I've had a hard time applying the articles I've read to my current code. I'm trying to save the value for whether a switch is switched and use that to determine it's state. How can I fix the Future bool vs bool error?

```
Widget learn(BuildContext context){
  bool isSwitched = _read();
  return Center(
    child: Switch(
      value: isSwitched,
      onChanged: (value) {
          _save(value);
          print(isSwitched);
      },
      activeTrackColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
      activeColor: Colors.green,
    ),
  );
}

Future<bool> _read() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final key = 'isSwitched';
  final value = prefs.getBool(key) ?? false;
  return value;
}

_save(bool boo) async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final key = 'isSwitched';
  final value = boo;
  prefs.setBool(key, value);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **_read** returns a **Future** but your **isSwitched** is a **bool** ...

You can use **FutureBuilder** then

```
  Widget learn(BuildContext context){
    return Center(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: _read(),
        builder: (context, snapshot){
          if(snapshot.hasData){
            return Switch(
              value: snapshot.data,
              onChanged: (value) {
                _save(value);
                print(snapshot.data);
              },
              activeTrackColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
              activeColor: Colors.green,
            );
          }else{
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt help. Unfortunately, when I made it into an async function, the "learn(BuildContext context){" turned returned a Future<widget>, which resulted in an error. How might I fix this?